# Read XML data into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a small XML fragment as shown below. I want to get:

- groupname attribute
- groupfilter expression attribute corresponding to groupname

I need to display these values as table so corresponding expression for group name is a must.

My XML file:

```xml
<datas xmlns:user="http://tempuri.org">
  <data>
    <group name='[Action (Market Size,Market,Product Type,Product)]' name-style='unqualified' user:auto-column='sheet_link'>
      <groupfilter function='crossjoin'>
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Market Size]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Market]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product Type]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product]' />
      </groupfilter>
    </group>
    <group name='[Action (Market,Product Type,Product)]' name-style='unqualified' user:auto-column='sheet_link'>
      <groupfilter function='crossjoin'>
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Market]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product Type]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product]' />
      </groupfilter>
    </group>
     <group name='[Set 1 sanu]' name-style='unqualified' user:ui-builder='filter-group'>
      <groupfilter expression='SUM([COGS]) == 0.' function='filter' user:ui-filter-by-field='true' user:ui-marker='filter-by'>
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product Line]' user:ui-enumeration='all' user:ui-marker='enumerate' />
      </groupfilter>
    </group>
    <group name='[Action (Category,Region,Sub-Category (group))]' name-style='unqualified' user:auto-column='sheet_link'>
      <groupfilter function='crossjoin'>
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Product Category]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Region]' />
        <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Sub-Category (group)]' />
      </groupfilter>
    </group>
    <group caption='Top Customers by Profit' name='[Set 1]' name-style='unqualified' user:ui-builder='filter-group'>
      <groupfilter count='[Parameters].[Parameter 2]' end='top' function='end' units='records' user:ui-marker='end' user:ui-top-by-field='true'>
        <groupfilter direction='DESC' expression='SUM([Profit])' function='order' user:ui-marker='order'>
          <groupfilter function='level-members' level='[Customer Name]' user:ui-enumeration='all' user:ui-marker='enumerate' />
        </groupfilter>
      </groupfilter>
    </group>
  </data>
</datas>
```

MY TRY:

(`root1` is the root element of etree parsing the xml as file)

```
for setvar in root1.findall('.//group'):
    setname.append(setvar.get('name'))
    groupfilter = setvar.findall('.//groupfilter')
    if groupfilter:
        for i in groupfilter:
            if i.get('expression'):
                setexpression.append(i.get('expression'))
             else:
                 setexpression.append('')
```

To display the result as a table, I appended them to a `list`. Is it possible to extract these two data as key,value pairs in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for conversion into a dict or list. Just use the XML tree as your base data structure.

```
for group in tree.iterfind('.//group'):
    for groupfilter in group.iterfind('.//groupfilter[@expression]'):
        groupname = group.get('name')
        expression = groupfilter.get('expression')

        print([groupname, expression])
```

This only selects `groupfilter` elements that actually have an `expression`.

Its just as easy to go through all `groupfilter` elements:

```
for group in tree.iterfind('.//group'):
    for groupfilter in group.iterfind('.//groupfilter'):
        groupname = group.get('name')
        expression = groupfilter.get('expression', '')  # default: empty string

        print([groupname, expression])
```

Comment: getting repeated values for name and expression @Tomalak

Comment: For the second code sample? Of course you do. When you look at your XML for a few moments you will see why.

Comment: yea, there are multiple groupfilters. But can i make some condition to return null(' ')  if expression attribute not found ? @Tomalak

Comment: If you only want to select the top-level `<groupfilter>` elements, not the nested ones, use `'./groupfilter'` instead of `'.//groupfilter'`.

Comment: There is no `null` in Python, but there is `None`. `.get()` will return `None` if you access undefined attributes, but in your question you seem to want an empty string instead, so that is what my code does. You'll figure out what to change.